# Exporting class with const member methods

Tags: c++, constants, dllexport

When I export a class with `const` member function in Visual Studio, running the user application results in a run-time error "Entry Point Not Found" for this function...

```
//header file
class EXPORT_API A
{
  //...
  void foo() const;
  //...
}

//cpp file
void A::foo() const
{
  //...
}
```

Interesting note. Demangling the "missing" function (copied from Dependency Walker and undecorated with demangler.com) looks like:

> public: void __cdecl A::foo(void)const __ptr64

, but when I "undecorate" the same function in Dependency Walker itself, const qualifier disappears...

However, everything works if I remove `const` specifier.

Why is this happening and how to export classes with `const` members?

Comment: Which platform are you working on?

Comment: Windows, Visual Studio

Comment: Did you try recompile all?

Comment: Have you looked at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/exe-entry-point-not-found/5b0866c1-8e45-457e-a83c-651c1fd307cc?

Comment: @amchacon Yes, I've tried to recompile everything from scratch without const - all works. Then repeat with const - fails

Comment: Are you defining the function in a header file? I think it might be possible that it is being inlined and not generated in your library. I assume you are generating a library.

Comment: Try defining the function in a cpp file.

Comment: I do define it in cpp already (edited the question)

Comment: You are exporting this from a DLL, right? It's been a long time since I tried to export a class. For years and years, I've exported a static construction function (`CreateXyz()`) that returns an interface. You can write a header-only wrapper type for the application to use to let you `new` and `delete` them.